# Keep jqplot settings on replot() chart

Tags: javascript, charts, jqplot

How do I keep jqplot options for max, min and numberTicks when I use

```
plot1.replot({resetAxes: true });
```

I get shifted chart on the both sideof x axis. Example: chart x axis starts with 0, when I execute replot, my x axis starts with -40.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the fix to your problem:

```
plot1.replot({
    resetAxes:true,
    axes: {
        xaxis: {
            show: true,
            label: "Date/Time",
            showLabel: false,
            showTicks: true,
            renderer:$.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer
        },
        yaxis: {
            label: 'y1',
            showLabel: false,
            tickInterval: y1AxisInterval,
            min: minYaxis,
            max: maxYaxis
        }
    }
});
```

Here you can specify your old max and min values, when you replot.